# Convert an INT value to a decimal with 2dp

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-conversion

I am trying to convert an INT value (i.e. 12345) to a decimal with 2dp. The example output should therefore become 123.45.

I am getting most of the data as INT values, I'd need a way to get the last two digits effectively to be part of the decimal place.

Comment: So, have you tried anything???  Have you even looked at the documentation?

Comment: Select convert(decimal(10,2),12345/100.0)  ... note the 100.0 otherwise an INT/INT will return an INT

Comment: Also, not clear on what you mean getting MOST of the data as INT.   Do you have some data with decimals?   If so, are you converting a STRING?

Answer (score -2):

How about just divide by 100?

```
select value/100 as value
from table;
```

Comment: Did you try Select 12345/100  ?   You would get 123 as an INT

Comment: one of the idiosyncrasies of sql server is that INT / INT performs INTEGER division which isn't what you want